# Nginx locations - case insensitive with spaces

Tags: nginx

My question is about nginx "location" configuration blocks:

If I want to make a location with a space character (well, %20) in the URL I can do it like so:

```
location ^~ "/Style Library/" {
}
```

If I want to make a case-insensitive location, I can do it like so:

```
location ~* ^/StyleLibrary/ {
}
```

However, I can't find a way of getting case-insensitive locations with space characters working.  None of these appear to work:

```
location ~* "^/Style Library/" {
}

location ~* ^/Style[^_]Library/ {
}

location ~* ^/Style\sLibrary/ {
}

location ~* ^/Style.Library/ {
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Do you have other regex locations that may be handling the request earlier in the server block?  I just ran a test locally and was able to make the following location work:

```
location ~* "^/Style Library/" {
  rewrite ^ /dump.php;
}
```

where /dump.php is just a simple script that does a var_export($_SERVER);

I tested this with

```
curl -i "dev/StYlE LiBrArY/"
```

I'd guess that some other location is handling the request instead of that regex location.